# Menu personalizado

Tags: python, funções

Estou criando um script simples com uma `def` que imprimi um menu personalizado. O primeiro parâmetro é o cabeçalho, seguido pelo número de itens acessíveis pelo menu e finalmente um terceiro parâmetro que é desempacotado na função, representando as chamadas do menu.
É apenas um treino, nada tão útil assim, mas sinto que o que está sendo entregue não é a solução mais elegante, apesar de simplificar bastante. Pode haver uma confusão com o número de itens e todos os elementos digitados para o último parâmetro.
Alguém tem alguma idéia melhor? Talvez com um nível de complexidade maior ou mais elegante, funcional, etc.. Ou acham que para a solução proposta seria isso mesmo? 
Segue o script:

```
def personalizado(txt, itens, *chamadas):
    print('-=-' * 15)
    print(txt.center(45))
    print('-=-' * 15)
    print()
    for c in range(0, itens):
        print(f'{c +1} - {chamadas[c]}')


# teste protegido
if __name__ == '__main__':
    personalizado('MENU QUALQUER', 6, 'Acessar', 'Visualizar', 'Cadastrar',
                  'Deletar', 'Reiniciar', 'Exit',)
```

O resultado:

```
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-
                MENU QUALQUER                
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-

1 - Acessar
2 - Visualizar
3 - Cadastrar
4 - Deletar
5 - Reiniciar
6 - Exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão, seria remover o segundo parâmetro (`itens`) da função `personalizado`, pois como você recebe no terceiro parâmetro uma tupla, você pode iterar nela e descobrir a quantidade, com isso, seu for poderia ficar assim:

```
for index, chamada in enumerate(chamadas):
    print(f'{index + 1} - {chamada}')
```

Como exemplo, utilizando o `enumerate` para já ter acesso a índice.

---

*Outras coisas que você pode fazer como aprendizado e testes seriam:*

Diminuir a quantidade de chamadas da função `print`, é possível utilizar o parâmetro `sep`, passando assim diversos parâmetros para ela e a separação seria uma quebra de linha:

```
print('-=-' * 15, txt.center(45), '-=-' * 15, '', sep='\n')
```

Criar o loop em apenas uma linha:

```
#list comprehension
[print(f'{index +1} - {chamada}') for index, chamada in enumerate(chamadas)]

#join da string que contém a quebra de linha
print('\n'.join(f'{index +1} - {chamada}' for index, chamada in enumerate(chamadas)))
```

---

Achei o uso do parâmetro `*chamadas` bem legal, a chamada da função fica mais simples, não tendo a necessidade de criar a lista.

---

> Exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/HelpfulPersonalPlan

Comment: Boa @DanielMendes, era isso mesmo que estava procurando. Evitar redundâncias, acabei observando estas mudanças ontem mesmo. Estava buscando uma forma de printar in-line também, foi perfeito! Obrigado!